# Is it possible to monitor and log all inbound/outbound network connections of an iOS Device programmatically in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, network-programming, swift3, ios10

I want to develop a Security-App for iOS-Devices and while I was brainstorming about the functionalities a question arose, which I wasn't able to answer by browsing through Google and other search engines:

Is it possible to get a list of all current inbound/outbound network connections of an iOS Device?

As I intend to write my application in Swift 3 I would be grateful for any hints/links/code examples.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As of iOS 10, this is no longer possible. Previous versions of iOS allowed this by using some undocumented APIs to access `sysctl` commands, but this loophole was closed. All apps that had this functionality, like "IT Tools", "Lirum", etc no longer work on iOS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not support packet tracing directly. However, if you connect your iOS device to a Mac via USB, you can use an macOS packet trace program to gather and analyze traces using the remote virtual interface feature.